How do I create an L-shaped button in Flutter?
I want make 2 (elevated) buttons, one (backwards) L-shaped, and one a regular rounded text, like this:

So far I can think of 3 approaches, but not sure how to implement any of them:

Use clip to clip out the inside of the L button, but I’m not sure how to get the rounded corners on the upper left portions correct; also I’m not sure how to ensure that the hit testing works right so the square button can actually be pressed.
Build the L button from some set of components, say two rounded texts, one horizontal the other vertical, using Stack or something to make them into one Widget, but then how do I make that Stack act like a single button?
Do some kind of CustomPaint, which seems hard to get all the curves right, especially as the buttons need to be dynamically sized, and then also I’d have to re-implement the logic of ElevatedButton to make it pressable, focusable, etc.

How would you lay out two buttons like this?

use ButtonStyle.shape - the docs say: "The shape of the button's underlying Material."

You can combine Stack and ShapeBorder for L button.
class LShapeBorder extends OutlinedBorder {
  @override
  OutlinedBorder copyWith({BorderSide? side}) => this;

  @override
  ui.Path getInnerPath(ui.Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection? textDirection}) =>
      getOuterPath(rect, textDirection: textDirection);

  @override
  ui.Path getOuterPath(ui.Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    // L shape
    final Path path = Path();

    final btnW = rect.width / 2 - 10;
    // path.moveTo(rect.right - btnW, rect.top);
    path.addRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromLTRB(rect.right - btnW, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom),
        const Radius.circular(8),
      ),
    );

    path.addRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromLTRB(rect.left, rect.bottom - btnW, rect.right, rect.bottom),
        const Radius.circular(8),
      ),
    );

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, ui.Rect rect,
      {ui.TextDirection? textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}

And usecase
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        fixedSize: Size.square(100),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        )),
                    onPressed: () {
                      debugPrint('1');
                    },
                    child: SizedBox(),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      shape: LShapeBorder(),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      debugPrint('2');
                    },
                    child: SizedBox(),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



I don't know for 100% if it was you who asked how to draw a polyline filled with a custom pattern, but even not you, it can be handy in some cases: https://gist.github.com/pskink/b86f5de25dd51d3b24f3994dea031357#file-main-dart

Your gist are always appreciated @pskink , I often visit to learn from you.

well, half of them are "secret gists" - not available for public ;-( (apropos your answer: some time ago I added the gist with a custom shape border so you don't have to create a custom shape from the scratch https://gist.github.com/pskink/7955c8f7a27a25e70d530648964cf2e5 - there are three examples included)
